# select attribute by mask

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have this

```
<a data-id-5='1'>1</a>
<a data-id-6='1'>2</a>
```

How can I select all attributes `data-id-*` with jquery, is it possible?

Comment: why? do you have any attribute data-id-5="2" ?

Comment: I would also look at why you have a structure like the one in the example, there might be a better way and it looks like it could be a headache to maintain or for other developers (other developers includes you a couple of months down the line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can then do it this way:

```js
$(function () {
  
    $('a').each(function () {
        $.each(this.attributes, function(i,n){
            if(!n.name.indexOf('data-id-')){
                $('body').append('<p>Name: ' + n.name + ' Value: ' + n.value +'</p>');
            }
        });
    });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a data-id-5='1' data-something-else='test'>1</a>
<a data-id-6='1'>2</a>
```

Comment: `data-id-5 is not valid, with multiple "-"` this is incorrect, it's perfectly valid: [HTML5 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#custom-data-attribute). Also, your example doesn't appear to contain the logic to match the required attributes, it just shows the data for each `a` element?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks, I changed my sentence ;) And you're right, it does not really answer the question.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I edited my answer. Does that answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you cannot achieve it directly. From [jQuery Doc](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/), it doesn't support such attribute selector.

What you can use is like `$([data-id])`. From [CSS Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/selector.html), the attribute selector does not support dynamic attribute name as well.

Anyway, putting the dynamic value as attribute name is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot with a single selector. If you know the number after `data-id-` you could do a loop, otherwise you need a specific element to query.

See [reference](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for more info on various ways to select.

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight forward method to it, however, you can do something like following

```
$(function(){


    $("a").each(function(){
        var dataAttributes = [];
        $.each(this.attributes, function() {
            // this.attributes is not a plain object, but an array
            // of attribute nodes, which contain both the name and value
            if(this.specified && this.name.indexOf("data-id-") > -1) {
                dataAttributes.push(this.name);
                // use this.value for value
            }
       });
       console.log(dataAttributes);

    });
});
```

For reference - http://plnkr.co/edit/tsUO89YT0tN6ToWBjPu9?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("a").data("id","*").each(function(){
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oar7x93w/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter()` to achieve this by retrieving the `dataset` from the underlying DOMElement and matching the `data-*` attribute names to a pre-defined Regex. Try this:

```js
var $a = $('a').filter(function() {
  for (var key in $(this)[0].dataset) {
    if (/^id-\d$/i.test(key))
     return this;
  }
})

// use the matched elements as you require...
$a.addClass('foo');
```

```css
.foo {
  color: #C00;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a>1</a>
<a data-id-5='1'>2</a>
<a>3</a>
<a data-id-6='1'>4</a>
```